# What is a word for "first of it's kind" or "unlike anything that came before it"?

Tags: synonyms

I have a recollection of a word that means something like "first of it's kind", or "unlike anything that came before it".

As in, "the original iPhone had a unique design that was unlike anything else in the industry - no fixed buttons, and an interface that was nothing but a sheet of glass..."

I think the word connotes new, radical, revolutionary, and significant.

I have a *very vague* recollection that the word was latin, like "de novo", but I'm pretty sure that wasn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Latin expression used at least by academics and which used to be in more common use.  It is the Latin from which *one of a kind* is derived.

> *sui generis*

This literally means that it is the only member of its type.  There is nothing like it.

Comment: Bingo. That's exactly the word(s) I couldn't remember. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Unprecedented is close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Ray - that word fits my criteria perfectly - thank you. But, not the one I'm looking for. This word was unusual (for me, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Groundbreaking  means just about what you asked for.

Comment: Walter - thank you  - groundbreaking fits my criteria perfectly. But, not the one I'm looking for. This word was very uncommon (for me, at least)

Comment: Pioneering might be better.